# Tracking user who register and paid in a site

Tags: google, google-analytics, tracking, analytics

We'd like to know which traffic sources converts the best on our site.

My problem is that i can't set up a single goal (payment succeeded), because users should have register first. Because we have a free plan there's a large chance users won't pay after registration but they'll experimenting with the app.

Is it possible to track back which original referral sources converts the most in this scenario in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Google analytic -> Goals flow and select a range like 1 month. It will tell you the sources of the sales like if you have 100 completed goals then how many of them are from Google , direct or referral.

Remember this will only work if you have already set the Goals URL for for month or so. If not then set it by adding Goal URL i.e. the URL appear right after the payment is transferred or another URL which appears after completing a transaction.